# Does error in opportunities cause impact in lighthouse scores?

Tags: javascript, performance, puppeteer, lighthouse

[image]

I am running the lighthouse tests using a puppeteer setup. When I turn on setrequestinterception in puppeteer the results for few opportunities don't get calculated in the report & get flagged as **Error**.

1. Any idea why this is this causing?
2. How can I overcome this issue?
3. Does this impact the total overall performance score of the report?

Comment: It will not solve your issue, but as a reminder, **do all your lighthouse scans in a private navigator** if you have extension. It can strongly impact your test.

Comment: Yes this is being done in a private tab. Thanks. Also can you let me know any other platform if not stackoverflow where I can post this issue? @crg